# Getting columns with equivalent values in rows

Tags: r

I need to get from a number of rows where some columns are equivalent and extract exactly those columns.

I have the following dataframe:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(1,2,3)
c <- c(4,5,6)
A <- data.frame(a,b,c)

> A
  a b c d
1 1 2 4 1
2 2 2 5 2 
3 3 3 6 3
```

I would like the following result:

```
> columnInnerJoin(A)
  a d 
1 1 1 
2 2 2 
3 3 3
```

Or, more specifically:

```
> columnInnerJoinGiveColumns(A)
  a d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `duplicated`

```
res <- A[duplicated(as.list(A))|duplicated(as.list(A), fromLast=TRUE)]
names(res)
#[1] "a" "d"
```